# Disabling application signing/integrity protection

Tags: catalina, security, xcode, code-signing, gatekeeper

I'm using a macOS 10.15 Parallels virtual machine for development purposes. It is very slow (compared to a macOS 10.13 VM), and I spend a couple of hours extracting XCode.

Now, when I try to open XCode (for the first time), after a really long wait time, I was greeted with a "verifying..." dialog with a extremely slow-moving progress bar. It seems like the progress only move once per half hour.

I tried to disable the behavior by:

- disabling gatekeeper (`spctl --disable-master`),
- disabling quarantine checks (`defaults write com.apple.LaunchServices LSQuarantine -bool NO`),
- and removing quarantine flags (`xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/XCode.app`),

but none works: I was still greeted by the slow-moving progress bar.

How can I completely disable notarization/quarantine/verification checks on macOS Catalina? It's a completely isolated VM so safety is not a concern.

My Mac is a 2017 MacBook Pro (13-inch, 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5, 16GB RAM).
I'm on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: How much RAM/CPU is assigned to the VM and have you tried giving the VM more of both?

Comment: 4 GB RAM and 2-core CPU with no throttling.

Comment: I tried to raise the RAM from 2GB to 4GB and it seems like things get a bit better.

Comment: But the VM actually never reaches 4GB of RAM usage, maximum is 3GB.

Comment: Thank you for testing. On the Catalina VM, could you open Activity Monitor, select the Memory tab and post a screenshot of the memory pressure graphic (at the bottom of the screen), including physical memory and swap usage? What Mac model (please include memory and processor information as displayed in Apple menu > About this Mac) do you have? Which macOS version are you on? If you open Xcode directly on your Mac, is it fast or slow?

Comment: @jaume Sorry for the late reply. When not verifying XCode, the memory pressure is green. I will try again when I have time and post an update. The mac model is 2017 MBP (13-inch, 3.1 GHz Intel Core i5, 16GB RAM). I'm on macOS High Sierra (I guess it's a bit old, but I don't have time for a fresh upgrade yet). Opening Xcode directly on my Mac takes about 2 seconds.